# Problemas com EventHandler .click() e .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quando eu uso `$('#nervID').mouseout(function(){/* ... */});` o `alert()` funciona e o `.animate()` funciona normalmente com a opacidade funcionando e sendo aplicada nos elementos com classe **.page**

O problema é que se eu mudo `.mouseout()` para `.click()` não funciona o `.animate()`. Testei com `background-color` também.

O engraçado é que ele dá o `alert()`, mas não aplica o `.animate()` quando uso `click()`.

Os outros *eventhandlers* (`.mouseout() .mousemove() .mouseover()`...) funcionam normalmente.

Alguém sabe o porquê disso acontecer?

HTML:

```
<div class="menucontainer"> 
    <ul class="gambiarraNav">
        <li class="navli"><a href="">   <p class="navp">Home</p></a></li>

        <li><a href=""><p class="navp">Pictures</p></a>
            <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Sub tab 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Sub tab 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Sub tab 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Sub tab 4</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li><a href=""><p class="navp">Asuka</p></a>
            <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Sub tab 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Sub tab 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Sub tab 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Sub tab 4</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li id="nervID"><a href="" ><p class="navp">Nerv</p></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#nervID').mouseout(function(){
    alert("entrou");
    $('.page').animate({'opacity':'0.00'}, 300, 'linear');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Em seu `<li id="nervID">` existe um link `<a href="" ><p class="navp">Nerv</p></a>`, quando você coloca a função para `onclick` não funciona, por que ao clicar, é assumido que você esta clicando no `link`, que em seu código leva para sua própria página, por isso emite o `alert` e o `animate` não funciona, você precisa adicionar um [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), assim quando o `click` é chamado o evento padrão do `href` não é acionado:

```
$('#nervID').click(function(event){
    alert("entrou");
    $('.page').animate({'opacity':'0.00'}, 300, 'linear');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Foi mais rápido :p

Comment: cara, muito obrigado pela explicação, agora posso seguir meus estudos! valeu mesmo,abraço.